# How to remove apache oozie completly?

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I want to remove oozie and reinstall a fresh copy.

I installed oozie by following this steps 
http://hadooptutorial.info/apache-oozie-installation-on-ubuntu-14-04/ Can anyone please help me to remove oozie completely from my laptop?

I am using ubuntu latest version ..with  hadoop 2.6.0 ..

Earlier I removed `/usr/lib/oozie` folder but it did not worked out for me after installing a fresh copy of oozie ..(got many errors and exception )

I am describing few of the errrors  below after installing fresh copy of oozie

1. oozie admin -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -status
   Connection exception has occurred [ java.net.ConnectException Connection refused ]. Trying after 1 sec. Retry count = 1
2. oozied.sh stop
   PID file found but no matching process was found. Stop aborted.
3. oozie-setup.sh sharelib create -fs hdfs://localhost:9000
   setting CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx1024m"

   Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/IOFileFilter

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

removing /usr/lib/oozie will not remove oozie entirely . 
Something more is require

Comment: You need to provide a more complete answer.